# Can a TCAS be alerted when the intruder aircraft has a transponder in stand-by mode?

Tags: safety, transponder, tcas

Can a TCAS give a TAs (traffic advisories) if the intruder aircraft has a transponder in stand-by mode?

Answer (score 6):

No. If the intruder's transponder is in standby it will not respond to interrogations and will be invisible to the TCAS. TCAS can't act on targets it can't interrogate.

Comment: A TCAS in standby mode still replies to discrete interrogation. What would happen if TCAS1 had already registered the presence of TCAS2 before  TCAS2 was switched to standby mode?

Comment: @mins It might work if the intruder was close enough to be put on the track list before the transponder was set to standby. TCAS can only issue a TA or RA when the intruder is actively interrogated. But even then, if it slides off the track list and it's in standby, the TCAS won't re-acquire it as there won't be a short squitter to announce it. Going forward, if TCAS2 has ADS-B out and TCAS1 has hybrid surveillance/ADS-B IN, it would be possible to see the aircraft on the display. but without a TA or RA.